# How to scan several strings with spaces?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

I want to scan words separated with spaces and written on several lines. I don't know the amount of words in advance. And I want to create std::vector of std::string. How to define the end of an input?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EB3J.png)

Comment: Please tag a particular standard of `c++` if and only if you're limited to that standard. Please don't tag multiple standards.

Comment: Business task is non-obvious. You can't make program magically undestand when to stop reading input.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! You tag a lot of c++ versions - Which c++ standard are you actuallly using? Makes no sense to tag all of them. Also, could you show some code of what you have tried so far, and an example in-/output? You must for sure have come across some examples of how to do something similar like this on the web?

Comment: Also, please take the [stackoverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), which will instruct you to place the code directly in the question.